# Can't set label.text from codebehind in ascx page

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid, ascx

I have a Telerik Radgrid that calls an .ascx control that allows the user to edit a larger dataset than is displayed in the actual Radgrid. It all works well except for one label I'm trying to set the text for. The raw data it has access to is just an ID, but I need it to display the person's name associated with that ID. So, I created a Function to get the required information and then set the label text. Sadly, that isn't working. I completely leave room for a stupid error, but I'm going bug-eyed trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I work alone so I can't even ask a fellow team member to help show how stupid I am. Here is my code:

ASCX.VB Codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    lblParentID.Text = GetParentID(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PartnerID"))
End Sub

Protected Function GetParentID(ByVal UID As Integer) As String
    Dim strConnString As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("XXXX").ConnectionString
    Dim varParent As String
    Using con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
        con.Open()
        Dim sqlParentCheck As String = "SELECT ParentID FROM [some table] WHERE PartnerID = @PID"
        Dim cmdParentCheck As New SqlCommand()
        Dim readerParentCheck As SqlDataReader
        cmdParentCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", UID)
        cmdParentCheck.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
        cmdParentCheck.CommandText = sqlParentCheck
        cmdParentCheck.Connection = con
        readerParentCheck = cmdParentCheck.ExecuteReader()

        If readerParentCheck.HasRows Then
            Dim ParentID_O As Integer = readerParentCheck.GetOrdinal("ParentID")
            Dim ParentID As Integer = readerParentCheck.GetInt32(ParentID_O)
            If ParentID = 0 Then
                varParent = "Account Admin"
            Else
                Dim sqlParentName As String = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Partners WHERE PartnerID = @PID"
                Dim cmdParentName As New SqlCommand()
                Dim readerParentName As SqlDataReader
                cmdParentName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", ParentID)
                cmdParentName.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
                cmdParentName.CommandText = sqlParentName
                cmdParentName.Connection = con
                readerParentName = cmdParentName.ExecuteReader()
                If readerParentName.HasRows Then
                    Dim ParentFName_O As Integer = readerParentName.GetOrdinal("FirstName")
                    Dim ParentFName As String = readerParentName.GetString(ParentFName_O)
                    Dim ParentLName_O As Integer = readerParentName.GetOrdinal("LastName")
                    Dim ParentLName As String = readerParentName.GetString(ParentLName_O)
                    varParent = ParentFName & " " & ParentLName
                End If
            End If
            Return varParent
        End If
    End Using
End Function
```

ASCX:

```
<asp:label ID="lblParentID" runat="server"></asp:label>
```

ASPX:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" ShowFooter="true"
                AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowStatusBar="true" AllowFilteringByColumn="true"
                OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender" Skin="Default" OnItemCreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" OnUpdateCommand="RadGrid1_UpdateCommand">
                <MasterTableView Width="100%" CommandItemDisplay="None" DataKeyNames="PartnerID">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn">
                        </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="AccountNumber" HeaderText="Account" DataField="AccountNumber">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="60px"></HeaderStyle>
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Company" HeaderText="Company" DataField="Company">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" DataField="FirstName">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" DataField="LastName">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Email" HeaderText="Email" DataField="Email">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditFormSettings UserControlName="UserDetails.ascx" EditFormType="WebUserControl">
                        <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1">
                        </EditColumn>
                    </EditFormSettings>
                </MasterTableView>
                <ClientSettings>
                    <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" OnPopUpShowing="onPopUpShowing" />
                </ClientSettings>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? That's a lot of code to go through and you could probably figure out how to make your question more specific if you can locate some unexpected behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't. This is a side project for a different dept and there is no "dev" environment that I have access to. I just imported the code to Visual Studio on my desktop (So, no database on my computer) and work on it there and re-upload to live. Terrible, I know, but nothing I can do about it in this situation.